# my visual force pagination doesn't work

Tags: visualforce

i have created a visualforce page with page navigation. I am able to shows the records but when i click next nothing happen. below is my controller:

```
public class sampleOutput5Cases {
private List<Case> ca;
private Contact cntact;
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setController{get; set;}

public sampleOutput5Cases (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.cntact= (Contact)controller.getRecord();
}

public List<Case> getCa()
//public void getCa()
{       
    ca = [Select id, CaseNumber, Origin, Status, Subject from Case where ContactId = :cntact.id];

    setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(ca); 
    setController.setPageSize(10);
    renderTable = true;

    return (List<Case>)setController.getRecords();
    //return ca;

}

public Boolean renderTable {
    get{
        if(renderTable == null)
            return false;
        return renderTable;

    }
    set;
}

public void Next()
{
    setController.Next();
}

public void Previous()
{
    setController.Previous();
}

/*public ApexPages.StandardSetController setController
{
    get
    {   
        if(cntact == null){
            List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
            return new ApexPages.StandardSetController(caseList);
        }else

        return setController;

    }
    set;
}*/

public Boolean getHasNext()
{
    if(setController==null)
        return false;
    return setcontroller.getHasNext();
}

public Boolean getHasPrevious()
{
    if(setController==null)
        return false;       
    return setcontroller.getHasPrevious();
}

public String getPageRangeText()
{
    if(setController == null)
        return '';
    else
    {
        Integer startP = ((setController.getPageNumber() - 1) * setController.getPageSize()) + 1;
        Integer endP;
        if(setController.getPageNumber()*setController.getPageSize() > setcontroller.getResultSize())
            endP = setcontroller.getResultSize();
        else
            endP = setController.getPageNumber()*setController.getPageSize();
        return 'Showing Records : ' + startP + ' - ' + endP + ' of total ' + setcontroller.getResultSize();
    }
}


public Boolean getShowPageRangeText()
{
    if (setController==null)
        return false;       
    if(setcontroller.getResultSize() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
} 

}
```

Comment: can you add the code for the page?

Comment: well worth reading -- http://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf Chapter 4

Comment: This is probably an issue with your VF as you will need to do a rerender of the table. Please post your VF markup.